# AttributeError while Implementing a timer

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to Implement a timer in my Object game, But it constantly gives me:

```
File "/home/nabeel/Desktop/game/ProjectGame/main.py", line 71, in call
         self.time_number = str(22)
     AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'time_number'
```

I can not understand as to why is this happening?

> The .py file

```
__version__ = "1.0"

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color

import random

Config.set('graphics', 'width', '480')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '320')
ImagesList = ['calculator','cards','facebook','fly','glasses','keys','mouse','wallet','webcam','pen']      

running = True

class ImgButton(Button):
    pass

class ListLabel(Label):
    pass

class MyWidget(AnchorLayout):

    level = 1
    LOC = []
    for i in range (10):
        LOC.append((random.randint(50,400),random.randint(0,260)))

    num = 9

    b_G_IMG = StringProperty("Level1/B_image1.png")
    time = 40
    time_number = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_number = str(self.time)


    def remove_rectangle(self, widget):
        if self.num > 0:
            self.grid_layout.remove_widget(widget)
            self.num -= 1
        else:
            self.level += 1
            self.set_level(self.level)
            self.num  = 9
            for i in range(9):
                new_image = ImgButton(background_normal= "Level1/"+str(ImagesList[i])+".png", pos = self.LOC[i])
                self.grid_layout.add_widget(new_image)
                new_image.bind(on_press=self.remove_rectangle)

                new_label = ListLabel(text=ImagesList[i],pos_y=(120+(i*10)))
                self.grid_layout.add_widget(new_label)

    def set_level(self,level):
        self.b_G_IMG = "Level"+str(level)+"/B_image"+str(level)+".png"


    def call(self):        
        self.time = self.time + 1
        self.time_number = str(self.time)


    Clock.schedule_interval(call, 1)    

    def ticked(self):
        self.time_number = 50
        running=False



class WidgetsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__=="__main__":
    WidgetsApp().run()
```

> The .kv file

```
<ListLabel@Label>
    halign:'left'
    font_size:15
    markup:True

<ImgButton@Button>:

    size_hint:(None,None)
    size:(60,60)


<MyWidget>:
    grid_layout: grid_layout
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            Image:
                source:root.b_G_IMG
        FloatLayout:
            Label:
                pos:(-200,120)
                font_size: 33
                text:':50'

        FloatLayout:
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,20)
                text:'[color=000000]Calculator[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,10)
                text:'[color=000000]Cards[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,0)
                text:'[color=000000]facebook[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-10)
                text:'[color=000000]fly[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-20)
                text:'[color=000000]glasses[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-30)
                text:'[color=000000]keys[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-40)
                text:'[color=000000]mouse[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-50)
                text:'[color=000000]wallet[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-60)
                text:'[color=000000]webcam[/color]'
            ListLabel:
                pos:(-200,-70)
                text:'[color=000000]Pen[/color]'            

        FloatLayout:
            size:(480,320)
            size_hint:(480,320)
            id: grid_layout

            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[0])
                background_normal: 'Level1/pen.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[1])
                background_normal: 'Level1/cards.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[2])
                background_normal: 'Level1/calculator.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[3])
                background_normal: 'Level1/fly.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[4])
                background_normal: 'Level1/glasses.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[5])
                background_normal: 'Level1/keys.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[6])
                background_normal: 'Level1/mouse.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[7])
                background_normal: 'Level1/wallet.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[8])
                background_normal: 'Level1/webcam.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
            ImgButton:
                pos:(root.LOC[9])
                background_normal: 'Level1/matches.png'
                on_press: root.remove_rectangle(widget=self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the clock in the `__init__` method, and pass `self.call` (rather than just `call`) to `schedule_interval`.

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time_number = str(self.time)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.call, 1)
```

This way, the method you're passing to `schedule_interval` is bound to this specific `MyWidget` object, and the object will be passed as the first argument to `call`. You also need to add a `dt` (delta-time) argument to `self.call`, since [one will be passed to the callback](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html). (You can just ignore the argument within the method).

```
    def call(self, dt):        
        self.time = self.time + 1
        self.time_number = str(self.time)
```